# PostGIS fields of type interval not part of QGIS' field list

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, dbmanager, properties

I have calculated a flight trajectory dataset from open data which has a couple of fields that can be used in GIS (3.32) without any troubles. but there seems to be a problem with fields of type "interval" in PostgreSQL/PostGIS. My first image shows the whole field-set in the PostGIS db. Two of these fields are interval-fields, where the "flight_overall_time"-field covers the information about the time when the tracking-app was on and "mean_time_diff" covers the average time between two consecutive tracking-points - which should be 1 second.

[image: posgis db - fieldset]

The second one shows the source of a layer in qgis - where I have specified a subset of these fields by a SELECT-statement in the Database Manager. [image: subset - Select field, field, field,]
as you can see the two type "interval" fields are part of that select !

The third one shows the field list in QGIS' layer properties / fields section - both of the "interval"-fiels are missing in that list.
[image: qgis layer properties / fields - missing fields]

The odd thing about that is, that a db-request in the QGIS Database Manager returns the correct results  - as you can see in the 4th img.
[image: qgis db manager - select & executed]

Obviously interval-fields cause some problems or aren't even types that can be used in QGIS. Are there any workarounds to transform these types within the SELECT that opens access to that information?

Answer (score 6):

The supported PostgreSQL data types are documented in https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html#support-of-postgresql-data-types

> Data types supported by the PostgreSQL provider include: integer,
> float, boolean, binary object, varchar, geometry, timestamp, array,
> hstore and json.

So no support for "interval". Maybe a workaround could be to use `TO_CHAR(interval,format)` or `EXTRACT(field FROM interval)` as in https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-interval/.